# Equivalence of axiom of choice

Tags: logic, category-theory, axiom-of-choice

I need to show that the assertion 'If $\mathcal{C}_{0}$ is a skeleton of a small category $\mathcal{C}$, then $\mathcal{C}\simeq \mathcal{C}_{0}$' implies that, given a family $(A_{i}\mid i\in I)$ of nonempty sets, we can find a family $(A_{i}^\prime \mid i\in I)$ where each $A_{i}^\prime$ is a nonempty finite subset of $A_{i}$.

For that I have used the category whose objects are the members of $I\times \{0,1\}$ and the morphisms $(i,j)\longrightarrow (i,k)$ are finite sums $\sum_{s=1}^{t}n_{s}a_{s}$ where $a_{s}\in A_{i}$ and $n_{s}$ integers with $\sum n_{s}=k-j$.

The objects of $\mathcal{C}_{0}$ have to be $(i,j)$ for each $i$, and $j=0$ or $j=1$ ($(i,0)$ and $(i,1)$ are in the same isomorphism class).

Since $\mathcal{C}_{0}\simeq \mathcal{C}$, we have functors $F\colon \mathcal{C}_{0} \longrightarrow \mathcal{C}$ and $G \colon \mathcal{C} \longrightarrow C_{0}$ such that there is a natural isomorphism from $1_{\mathcal{C}}$ to $FG$ and another one from $GF$ to $1_{\mathcal{C}_{0}}$.

Then, by taking any morphism $f\colon (i,j) \longrightarrow (i,k)$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $G(f)\colon (i,j) \longrightarrow (i,j)$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{C}_{0}$, and I can take the set $A_{i}^\prime$ to have the elements of the summand.

However, I am not using any of my hypothesis (the functor $F$ and the two natural isomorphisms), so something has to be wrong. Can anyone help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: Removing the first paragraph renders the now-second paragraph completely incomprehensible. What does "a similar process" mean now? Similar to what?

Comment: How do you compose morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$? Formal addition of the finite sums?

Comment: @AsafKaragila sorry, I have just wanted to be clearer.

Comment: @AlexKruckman yes!

Comment: The error in your proof is when you say "by taking any morphism $f\colon (i,j)\to (i,k)$...". You have to pick such an $f$ for every $i\in I$, so you're using Choice here.

Comment: @AlexKruckman that's true! I have so internalized the Axiom of Choice that it is difficult for me not to use it. However, since I have the natural transformation isomorphism between $1_{\mathcal{C}}$ and $FG$, for $(i,j)$ I have an isomorphism that goes from $(i,j)$ to $FG(i,j)$, so I use the elements of the finite sum of that morphism. Would that be ok?

Comment: @Laura And what if that morphism is the $0$ sum?

Comment: @AlexKruckman That is true :( I have no idea of how to solve that problem...

Comment: @AlexKruckman I don't know if it still interests you, but I have finally solved the problem :) I am going to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume that the objects of $\mathcal{C}_{0}$ are $(i,0)$ for $i\in I$.

If $F\colon \mathcal{C}_{0} \longrightarrow \mathcal{C}$ and $G\colon \mathcal{C}\longrightarrow \mathcal{C}_{0}$ are functors such that there is a natural isomorphism $\beta \colon FG\longrightarrow 1_{\mathcal{C}}$, one of $\beta_{(i,0)}$ or $\beta_{(i,1)}$ has a formal addition distinct to $0$, so we may take the elements of that finite sum.

Comment: It does still interest me! Why must one of the components of $\beta$ be nonzero?

Comment: We know that $G(i,0)$=$G(i,1)$, so $FG(i,0)=FG(i,1)$. Suppose that they are equal to $(i,0)$. In that case, since $\beta_{(i,1)}$ goes from $FG(i,1)$ to $(i,1)$, the addition would be distinct to $0$ because the sum of the coefficients has to be equal to 1-0=1 (I don't know if my explanation is clear enough...)

Comment: Ah, I missed your edit to the definition of the category in the question. Nice solution.